# How to handle proxying to multiple services with golang and labstack echo

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and Micro-services development, but I hope my question will make sense:

Let's say I have a micro-service handling users actions such as creating, showing & updating an user, available at `localhost:8081/users`.

Beside that, I have a micro-service handlings events' creation, show & update as well, available at `localhost:8082/events`.

And, above that, there is a gateway, available at `localhost:8080` which is suppose to act as a proxy to dispatch the incoming request to the right service.

I found this piece of code which is working well to redirect from my gateway to my user's service:

```
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
    Scheme: "http",
    Host:   "localhost:8081",
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)
```

But two things are bothering me:

- How am I suppose to handle dispatching on multiple micro-services? I'd like to have a condition such as: "If the client requests `localhost:8080/users` it should go to the user's service. If he requests `localhost:8080/events` it should go to the event's service. (Please feel free to tell me if this approach is just wrong)
- As I mentioned in the title, I'm using the labstack/echo Router, so I don't want to start my server with `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)`, but with something like

  `e := echo.New()
   e.Start(":8080")`

  But I can't find how to pass a proxy as parameter with this tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to an answer on an issue I posted on labstack/echo github, here is the solution:

`httputil.ReverseProxy` implements `http.Handler`, so you can do something like:

```
e := echo.New()
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
    Scheme: "http",
    Host:   "localhost:8081",
})
e.Any("/users", echo.WrapHandler(proxy))
e.Start(":8080")
```